# Features comparison between Hibernate and eclipseLink

Tags: hibernate, orm, eclipselink

I want to see the most relevant differences between Hibernate and eclipselink (features). What do we take into account to choose one or other of them ? what has hibernate that eclipselink hasn't ?

Thanks